# Yesod Persistent functions inaccessible from Handler. What should I include?

Tags: haskell, scaffolding, yesod, include-path, persistent

I'm having trouble with a slightly altered Yesod scaffold. I've got my Entity described like so in /config/models:

```
Artist
    ident Int
    value Text
```

and here is my handler at /Handler/Artist.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TypeFamilies, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, TemplateHaskell,
             OverloadedStrings, GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}
module Handler.Artist where

import Import
import qualified Control.Monad.IO.Class as M
import Text.Hamlet (shamlet)
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml)
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

getArtistR = concatMap (renderListElement . value) $ artists
  where artists = selectList ([] :: [Filter Artist]) []
        renderListElement name = renderHtml [shamlet|<li>#{name}|]
```

(I included with redundancy :) )

And lastly, my errors:

```
Rebuilding application... (using cabal)

Handler/Artist.hs:14:45: Not in scope: `value'
Build failure, pausing...
```

I'm not sure what I should do! Do I need to throw in something like `$(widgetFile "artist")` in the handler? Where is the patching going wrong? Any help would be so awesome. Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should prefix functions with model name, so `value` becomes `artistValue`.

Documentation contains [example](http://www.yesodweb.com/book-1.2/persistent#_code_generation) of generated code.